# Missile rule clarification

Tags: risk-legacy

"Any player (even those not involved in the battle) may discard
Missile(s) after dice are rolled, but before troops are removed.
For each Missile discarded in this way, the player can change
one die in the combat roll to an unmodifiable 6. A player may
discard multiple Missiles to change multiple dice per battle.

Players may discard Missiles in any order and may respond to
another player using a Missile by using a second (or more). If
two or more players are trying to play a Missile at the same time,
priority goes to the current player (attacker), then the defender,
then each player clockwise around the table from the attacker."

A few questions here really first, "unmodifiable 6" (1)does that mean it can only be a 6? and(2) does that prevent another missile from "modifying" it to something else?

I play with a group who has routinely messed this up either way. For instance a single die was changed from 6 to 1 and back again several times just last week. If it gets changed to a 6 it can't change back according to the rule I read. But I am only one at a table of 5. Any help in this would be appreciated.

Comment: From the rules you quoted, it sounds like missiles can only be used to change die rolls to a 6. Why are you using them to change them to a 1? The unmodifiable presumably applies to +1 effects from fortified areas or something.

Comment: I haven't played Risk Legacy before, and I know some of the rules can change as you play, but Nick's comment seems spot on unless there has been a rule change unsealed that modifies this (I just don't know if there are any as again I have never played).

Answer (score 5):

**Missiles change a die into a '6' only. A missile can never modify a die to anything else.**

Perhaps a non-spoilerific example might clarify.

- An attack roll on a **Ammo Shortage** territory is 6,5,1 versus a defense roll of 5,5. The defender's high die is reduced by 1 because of the Ammo Shortage's -1 modifier making their roll 5,4. The defender uses a missile on the '4' making it an unmodifable '6' (Ammo Shortage can no longer affect it), and the attacker loses 2 troops instead of the defender (6,5,1 vs 6,5 after missile instead of 6,5,1 vs 5,4 before missile)

Comment: This tallies with designer Rob Daviau's explanation here: http://boardgamegeek.com/article/7989409#7989409